# An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**using gem magick' and am using rails 3.1.0**

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/.........

Fetching additional metadata from http://rubygems.org/..

Resolving dependencies...


Using rake (10.1.1)
Using multi_json (1.8.4)
Using activesupport (3.1.0)
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
Using builder (3.0.4)
Using i18n (0.6.9)
Using activemodel (3.1.0)
Using erubis (2.7.0)
Using rack (1.3.10)
Using rack-cache (1.0.3)
Using rack-mount (0.8.3)
Using rack-test (0.6.2)
Using hike (1.2.3)
Using tilt (1.3.7)
Using sprockets (2.0.4)
Using actionpack (3.1.0)
Using mime-types (1.25.1)
Using polyglot (0.3.4)
Using treetop (1.4.15)
Using mail (2.3.3)
Using actionmailer (3.1.0)
Using arel (2.2.3)
Using tzinfo (0.3.38)
Using activerecord (3.1.0)
Using activeresource (3.1.0)
Using ansi (1.4.3)
Using bundler (1.5.2)
Using carrierwave (0.5.8)
Using coffee-script-source (1.7.0)
Using execjs (2.0.2)
Using coffee-script (2.2.0)
Using rack-ssl (1.3.3)
Using json (1.8.1)
Using rdoc (3.12.2)
Using thor (0.14.6)
Using railties (3.1.0)
Using coffee-rails (3.1.1)
Using jquery-rails (3.1.0)
Using mysql2 (0.3.15)
Using rails (3.1.0)


Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb 
checking for Ruby version >= 1.8.5... yes
checking for gcc... yes

checking for Magick-config... no
Can't install RMagick 2.13.2. Can't find Magick-config in /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.


Provided configuration options:

    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1


Gem files will remain installed in /home/rithujadav/.bundler/tmp/3624/gems/rmagick-2.13.2 for inspection.

Results logged to /home/rithujadav/.bundler/tmp/3624/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/ext/RMagick/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing rmagick (2.13.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: have u tried gem install rmagick before bundle install

Comment: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev`

Comment: After @RaghvendraParashar's answer, run `gem install rmagick`

Answer (score 68):

You should install ImageMagick first:

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick libmagickcore-dev libmagickwand-dev
```

Comment: I had to install `libmagickwand-dev` to make it work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 38):

On Mac, I did `brew install imagemagick`.

That successfully allowed me to run `gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'` without issues.

Comment: works for 2.15.4 as well.

Comment: Homebrew FTW!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

or

```
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH"
```

and then `$ gem install rmagick` should work

Comment: here's what i did on 16.04,
sudo apt-get install libmagickwand-dev
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick-imagemagick-compat
PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6.8.9/bin-Q16:$PATH" gem install rmagick -v '2.13.2'

Comment: @JamesMaynard, thanks a lot, exporting the PATH helped me. However, I didn't enter the PATH like that directly in the command line to avoid overriding other pathes, but I added it to .bashrc like described here: http://askubuntu.com/a/60219/329695